# Why can't I junk certain jewelry?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

During my travels, I've found some jewelry that wasn't worth keeping and so I threw it in my junk bag so I could easily sell it later on. Recently, I found this interesting piece:

[image]

This item is called St. Hadwyn's Beads. As you can see in the picture, it's equip-able and I have the option of comparing it with my other items. However, I don't want to use this poor excuse for jewelry as it has no magical properties whatsoever. And when I can't use something, I junk it so it can be sold. But, there's no 'junk' option on this item. What's so special about it? Are there others out there like it?

Comment: Could it be related to a quest?

Comment: I too found this item and was curious. I'm wondering if it's quest related for something that isn't unlocked / obtained yet, as I previously had gotten a quest item for a quest I didn't have yet, meaning it's certainly possible.

Comment: @Sterno I have no idea. I had a quest-related necklace earlier and it didn't show up under jewelry. But I guess it could depend on what kind of quest it was (main, task, etc). If it is, I'm hoping someone has done it and can tell me. I'm stingy with my inventory space :p

Comment: @TheQ Yeah, I've had that happen too so I definitely want to make sure this isn't before I try and sell it off.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I know while playing, the game has not let me sell, destroy, or put in my junk bag any quest items, so I'm guessing that's the cause. While I don't have firsthand knowledge of your particular item, [I did find some info on it](https://segmentnext.com/2012/02/07/kingdom-of-amalur-reckoning-side-quests-guide/#ixzz1loBGJeaK).

> **Brother Fallon’s Beads**
>
> St. Hadwyn’s Beads is an accessory which you’ll
> get in the Plaguseshield. You will not be able to thrash it, go to St.
> Hadwyn Mission (Glendara) and talk to Brother Udo. Make sure that you
> make him certain that you believe in the ways of Mitharu in order to
> trigger this quest.

So it sounds to me like it's a quest item for a quest you don't have yet.

Comment: I'm guessing you're right. I just found another set of beads but these had magical properties and do have the junk option. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

its part of a side quest. when you talk to Udo you'll inform him that brother Fallon is dead and he will tell you to keep beads and to pray at the 3 shrines at the missions. Each time it will give bonus to beads.