# What should I do with The Treasures of Meropis?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

While exploring the Fae Library I triggered a quest called **The Treasures of Meropis**. I basically had to recover lost items from various underwater places. I found all five treasures which included:

- Bag of Sand
- Coral Silver
- Shell
- Meropic Relic
- Pearl

After I found the last one, the game told me that I completed the quest. Now the treasures are just sitting in my inventory taking up space and I hate having useless things in my inventory. I have no further information about the items. So I'm wondering: now what? Should I hang on to these for any reason or can I just sell them off?

Comment: Is there not some location in the library where you can put them on display?  That's how some of the other "collect all the X" quests have ended for me.

Comment: @agent86 I haven't looked there. I'll try it and let you know. Did it actually tell you to do it when the text completed?

Comment: @agent86 Well, I just tried the library and there wasn't an option to display them there. Hmmmm....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that all the other quest items in the game, [even the ones for quests you don't have yet](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/50110/3062), seem to be unsellable, I think it's safe to sell these off. [Some Googling](http://www.ign.com/wikis/kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning/The_Treasures_of_Meropis) backs up the idea that they aren't used anywhere else:

> Once you collect all five treasures scattered over Dalentarth (track
>   the mission and see the locations), you complete the mission. Sell (or
>   stash) all five if you like; they are worth roughly $800 per item
>   (with no Mercantile skill increase).

On a related note, I tested and you can actually sell them off while the quest is still in progress. It's finding them that triggers progress and completion, not possessing them. So you can sell them off as you go to free up inventory space and the Treasures of Meropis quest will still complete. There is no need to wait until the end and sell them all at once.